# Struts2 get original request URI

Tags: struts2

I want to get the current request uri from inside a jsp page in a struts2 webapp. I can do this in an action using the following:

```
ServletActionContext.getRequest().getRequestURI()
```

... and I supposed technically I could then create a property of the action that just returns that value but I would rathern not write it into the action, is there a way I can access the same value in a jsp using an ognl expression?

EDIT: 
After a bit more playing about I have realised that even if I can get the HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI() value in the jsp page by the time I get it, it will have changed to the path of the jsp not the original request URI so will not be what I want.

So instead what I have done is write an interceptor that grabs the value early on before the request is dispatched to the jsp file and then save it in the value stack which I can then  refer to it in the jsp. This may be the only solution but if anyone knows different then do enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:url/>
```

This question [Tiles2 Struts Switch Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773063/tiles2-struts-switch-locale) shows an application of the  tag and shows how to maintain the parameters on the url (which might be useful for later).

Comment: Douh! I should have known that. Thanks.