# Struts2 OGNL - Request parameters submission order

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I am using jsp and struts2, and I have the following scenario:

```
<s:form>
<s:hidden name="empId" value="123"/>
<s:textfield name="employee.name"/>
<s:submit action="save"/>
</s:form>
```

When this form is submitted, the OGNL expression employee.name (equivalent to getEmployee().setName()) gets executed before "save" method. And, the value for "empId" is not available inside the method getEmployee(). The value for "empId" is available only inside the "save" method. Is it possible to get the value of "empId" inside getEmployee()?

Following is the code in my Action class:

```
public String save() {
  //empId is available here
  return SUCCESS;
}

public Employee getEmployee(){
  if (employee == null){
    //empId is not available here
    employee = employeeService.get(empId);
  }
  return employee;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the relevent struts2 xml/annotations it is generally easier for us to read that then it is to read the english version.

Comment: Quaternion, thanks for the reply. I have edited the question to be more clear. Please check if you are able to understand the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I assume that you *do* have a setter for the `empId` field (you didn't show one) and that your problem is that the order in which the parameters are being set is arbitrary.

There is an option for the `ParametersInterceptor` to force it to set top-level properties first. You can enable it by customizing your interceptor stack to define the parameters interceptor with the `ordered` property set.

```
<interceptor-ref name="params">
    <param name="ordered">true</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Then, in your action class, change the `setEmpId` method to:

```
public void setEmpId(Integer empId) { // or whatever type it is
    this.empId = empId;
    employee = employeeService.get(empId);
}
```

As an alternative to the setter approach, you could also create a type converter for the `Employee` class and then change your form to:

```
<s:form>
    <s:hidden name="employee" value="123"/>
    <s:textfield name="employee.name"/>
    <s:submit action="save"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I added the property "ordered" for "params" interceptor and it worked like a charm! Thanks once again for the suggestion.

Comment: My pleasure! I found it really useful when I ran across it too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand so to be clear, you want to call getEmployee() and you don't know how to get the employee id in the method?

Lets say you have a table of employees. Lets also assume that the table provides the following details:

- employee name
- employee id

Lets assume that there is a link also in each row which when clicked will take you to an employee details screen for that employee. Since you have just printed the employee id you can also construct an html anchor element with the required get parameters so when the action is called you'll have what you need.  The `<s:a>` tag along with the `<s:param>` tag make this easy.

See my answer here [Tiles2 Struts Switch Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773063/tiles2-struts-switch-locale/4776321#4776321) for an example of how to use struts2 anchor tag and properties tag. Although that example makes use of static properties just replace the value attribute in the parameter tag with the id variable.

See http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/a.html for more details.

**Edit**: I see now I was way off before your edit.

I think the easiest thing would be to make a getEmployee(int id) method. Then you can get rid the the hidden field value too.
After that it should be straight forward...

Your jsp would look roughly like (not tested):

```
<s:form>
   <s:textfield name="%{employee[123].name}"/>
   <s:submit action="save"/>
</s:form>
```